# How to get token using Cloud Foundry api?

Tags: oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to get token from Cloud Foundry. I'm getting token from `cf oauth-token` command but I try using curl its giving me an error:

```
{
  "description": "Unknown request",
  "error_code": "CF-NotFound",
  "code": 10000
}
```

The Curl command I'm using:

```
curl 'https://<domian>/oauth/token' -X POST \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
        -H 'Accept: application/json
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May not be what you want, but I often take the lazy path in my scripts and do this: `curl -H "Authorization: $(cf oauth-token)" "https://api.system_domain/v2/..."` (you can use the token for any endpoint, not just CAPI). That requires `cf` cli to be installed and logged in, but it's super easy to get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on used flow. See doc: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/4.31.0/index.html#authorization